# How can I keep the value of a variable outside a function?

Tags: json, swift, xcode, augmented-reality, arkit

I'm trying to display the value I get from a JSON in an AR text, within the DecodeJSON function it all works, I even achieve to put that value in a normal label but when I try to set that value to the AR text it is empty... what can I do or what I'm doing wrong? It would be very useful if you can help me out with this.

```
@IBOutlet var sceneView: ARSCNView!
@IBOutlet weak var labelTest: UILabel!

let URL_VWC = "http://w1.doomdns.com:11000/restaguapotable/api/celula/10/sitio/4";

var name :String!

struct JSONTest: Codable {
    let Nombre: String
    let Tiempo: String
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    // Set the view's delegate
    sceneView.delegate = self

    // Show statistics such as fps and timing information
    sceneView.showsStatistics = true

    // Create a new scene
    let scene = SCNScene()

    // Set the scene to the view
    sceneView.scene = scene
    DecodeJson();


    let text = SCNText(string: name, extrusionDepth: 1.0)
    text.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.black

    let textNode = SCNNode(geometry: text)
    textNode.position = SCNVector3(0,0, -0.5)
    textNode.scale = SCNVector3(0.02,0.02,0.02)

    sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(textNode)
}


func DecodeJson(){
    guard let url = URL(string: URL_VWC) else { return }

    // 2
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error!.localizedDescription)
        }

        guard let data = data else { return }
        do {
            // 3
            //Decode data
            let JSONData = try JSONDecoder().decode(JSONTest.self, from: data)
            // 4
            //Get back to the main queue
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.name = JSONData.Nombre
                self.labelTest.text = self.name
            }

        } catch let jsonError {
            print(jsonError)
        }
        // 5
        }.resume()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This means that `DecodeJson()` returns  `self.name = JSONData.Nombre` after `let text = SCNText(string: name, extrusionDepth: 1.0)` is called.

You should have a separate function where you setup your scene after the `DecodeJson()` has returned the JSON